# How can I capture/record the data being sent to the printer (from different types of softwares) using Python?

Tags: python, csv

I need to capture and then analyse the data being sent to the printer, preferably using python (data would be on various reports produced from the softwares on my PC). As data/reports for printng could be from many different softwares so change at the each individual software level is out of the scope,

Later on, this captured/recorded data will be (or made available to) entered in another system.

Thanking in anticipation